# closed form expression $\int_{0}^{\infty}[1-\epsilon e^{-\mu(z-\alpha)}]^n \lambda e^{-\lambda \alpha} d\alpha$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the following integration (closed form solution)

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}[1-\epsilon e^{-\mu(z-\alpha)}]^n \lambda e^{-\lambda \alpha} d\alpha
$$
I tried using substitution and then using beta function definition [$\beta(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1}dt$]  to get the closed form solution as taking $y=\epsilon e^{-\mu(z-\alpha)}$ and the interval is (after substation).
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}[1-y]^n y^{-1-\frac{\mu}{\lambda}} dy
$$
which is unsolvable or the integral goes to infinity (using matlab).

Comment: What are the values of the other parameters $\mu, \lambda, \varepsilon, z$ in the integral? The convergence, divergence, and possible closed form of the integral heavily depend on if these values are positive, negative, or $0$.

Comment: The lower bound is not $0$ and, depending on the sign of $\mu$, the upper bound is $0$ or $\infty$

Comment: The values are unknown (real numbers), $\epsilon \in [0,1], \lambda, \mu > 0$. Yes all of them are positive.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici why it does matter the sign of $\mu$. I am integrating over $\alpha$

Comment: Did someone delete their answer? See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1kKy.jpg). I do not see it. Also see the common [Incomplete Beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). Maybe it simplifies?

Answer (score 0):

With help of Mathematica I have:

$$\int_0^{\infty } (1-\epsilon  \exp (-\mu  (z-\alpha )))^n \lambda  \exp (-\lambda  \alpha ) \, d\alpha =\\\lambda  \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda  \left(z+\frac{i \pi }{\mu }\right)} \epsilon ^{\lambda /\mu }
   \Gamma \left(-n+\frac{\lambda }{\mu }\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{\lambda }{\mu }\right)}{\mu  \Gamma (-n)}+\frac{\, _2F_1\left(-n,-\frac{\lambda }{\mu };1-\frac{\lambda }{\mu };e^{-z \mu } \epsilon
   \right)}{\lambda }\right)=\\\lambda  \left(\frac{e^{-\lambda  \left(z+\frac{i \pi }{\mu }\right)} \epsilon ^{\lambda /\mu } \Gamma \left(-n+\frac{\lambda }{\mu }\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{\lambda
   }{\mu }\right)}{\mu  \Gamma (-n)}-\frac{e^{-z \lambda } \epsilon ^{\lambda /\mu } \lambda  B_{e^{-z \mu } \epsilon }\left(-\frac{\lambda }{\mu },1+n\right)}{\mu  \lambda }\right)$$

Mathematica code:

`Integrate[(1 - \[Epsilon] Exp[-\[Mu] (z - \[Alpha])])^ n*\[Lambda] Exp[-\[Lambda] \[Alpha]], {\[Alpha], 0,  Infinity}] == \[Lambda] (( E^(-\[Lambda] (z + (I \[Pi])/\[Mu])) \[Epsilon]^(\[Lambda]/\[Mu]) Gamma[-n + \[Lambda]/\[Mu]] Gamma[-(\[Lambda]/\[Mu])])/(\[Mu] \ Gamma[-n]) +  Hypergeometric2F1[-n, -(\[Lambda]/\[Mu]), 1 - \[Lambda]/\[Mu],  E^(-z \[Mu]) \[Epsilon]]/\[Lambda]) == \[Lambda] (( E^(-\[Lambda] (z + (I \[Pi])/\[Mu])) \[Epsilon]^(\[Lambda]/\[Mu]) Gamma[-n + \[Lambda]/\[Mu]] Gamma[-(\[Lambda]/\[Mu])])/(\[Mu] \ Gamma[-n]) - ( E^(-z \[Lambda]) \[Epsilon]^(\[Lambda]/\[Mu]) \[Lambda] Beta[ E^(-z \[Mu]) \[Epsilon], -(\[Lambda]/\[Mu]),  1 + n])/(\[Mu]*\[Lambda]))`

If: $\epsilon <e^{z \mu }\land n \mu <\lambda \land e^z\leq \epsilon ^{1/\mu}$

Comment: Use [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0006/) to simplify the $\,_2\text F_1(a,b;b,z)$. Also $$(-n)_\frac \lambda \mu=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac \lambda \mu-n\right)}{\Gamma(-n)}$$ with the [pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk The result contain imaginary values right?

Comment: @MunaTageldin Yes